# Signals over rows forecasting

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, signals, forecasting

I need to forecast signals from some sensors. In every guide and documention I found examples of forecasting time series when every column is a different feature and time samples are distributed alongside the rows.

In my case I have got one signal per row, hence time samples over columns and sensors over rows. Sensors should share some kind of statistical properties for predictions so I would like to train the network over the rows in order to predict the trend of each signal.

It's the first time I try such thing and I have some problems in dealing with machine learning with time series. Do you have any examples displaying such kind of learning techniques?
Would transpose the matrix just do the trick?

P.S. I'm using Python with Keras for NN.

Comment: Yeah, transposing would be the way to go. The data doesn't change.

Comment: The number of signals is very high though (few thousands by heart) so I would obtain a very huge number of "features"